# Is it possible to Pool together CPU Cores into 1 Fast Core

Tags: cpu

I host game servers around the world, Some of those require very high clock speeds due to heavy load on the server.
My question is this:
Is it possible to take for example an 8 Thread CPU at 3Ghz and use something like virtualization to make it an 4 Thread CPU at 6Ghz?
I want to pool my CPU together into one or multiple faster cores so that single thread applications can use more of the CPU.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer : NO !

There is no magic allowing to converting a multithread CPU into a faster, higher frequency single thread CPU. The proliferation of multithread and multicore CPUs stems from the complexity of raising even more single-thread performance.

The CPUs internal resources, ALUs (arithmetic units), LSUs (load-store) present in several instances in high end multithread CPUs can be used by several threads simultaneously, or used by one thread, giving it higher priority and performance (there are also thermal tradeofs, and due to internal limitations, some CPU resources, as load/store queues or operational units, may not be available for all threads).

The IBM Power8 CPU is an example of a CPU with dynamically configurable number of threads (8 threads max per core)